# Escaping T-SQL Keywords

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, php

```
$sql = "SELECT Kill FROM tbl_pvporderview";
```

Problem is that I end up with: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Kill'`.

Because `kill` is a T-SQL command... any way to bypass it?

I can't change the column name because it's used by the software a lot and I cant change the software that's using the database.

So it simply fails if I use `sqlserv` to select data from that column. '' or "" wont help.

The complete statement would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT serial,Kill FROM tbl_pvporderview WHERE Kill > (?) ORDER BY Kill DESC ";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use reserved words as table or column names, you have 2 options:

use brackets (the SQL-Server's way): `SELECT [Kill]`

or double-quotes<sup>*</sup> (the ANSI/ISO standard): `SELECT "Kill"`

Your whole statement would become:

```
SELECT [serial], [Kill] 
FROM tbl_pvporderview 
WHERE [Kill] > (?) 
ORDER BY [Kill] DESC ;
```

<sup>*: Of course, using double quotes (`SELECT "Kill"`) would necessitate that `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is `ON`. You may encounter databases that the setting is still `SET OFF`.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the column name in square brackets:

```
$sql = "SELECT [Kill] FROM tbl_pvporderview";
```